# How to efficiently extract specific json from large zip in browser?

Tags: javascript, optimization, unzip, zip

I want to extract files that are named `message_1.json` from a big (13 GB) zip file in a web browser (using javascript).

These files are located in `messages/inbox/some_random_name_xsfdscd/message_1.json`, `messages/inbox/some_random_name_sfasggf/message_1.json`, `messages/inbox/some_random_name_polsnbd/message_1.json` etc. in the zip file.

I tried using [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/). Unfortunately, it has to load the whole zip before it can process it. It takes too much time and memory often resulting in crashing the page.

Also, there is a library [zip-js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) which is able to get a tree of files before unzipping. However, it can't process zip files larger than 4 GB.

So, is it possible to extract only specific files from large zips in a web browser without taking too much memory and time? If yes, how?

Comment: I don't think you can partially unzip a zip file, but I'm curious to see what other people have to say.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.
I tried various npm packages: pako, unzipper, adm-zip, zip-js, fflate without luck.
Anyone found a solution to extract / deflate / decompress specific file from large .zip file without reading the entire zip file?